# Unable to locate the element using Xpath selenium C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

How can I get the highlighted value using Selenium C#?
[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses!!
Is there a way I can search for it without using a hard-coded value like the contains(text) & store it in a variable? this is because the text values will change.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

> //*[contains(text(),'Acura')]

Comment: Thanks for your response!! Is there a way I can search for it without using a hard-coded value like the contains(text) & store it in a variable? this is because the text values will change

Answer (score 1):

You can take xpath as below

> 1. //span[contains(text(),'Acura')]  - Specific to span tag.
>      **OR**
> 2. //*[contains(text(),'Acura')]  - Generic with any tag.

You can directly inspect your locators by using [Chropath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chropath-for-firefox/) plugin in Firefox or you can use internal inspector in Chrome.

If you are getting duplicate xpath with above so you can use **following-sibling**, **preceding-sibling** or [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) to get unique xpath.

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thanks for your response!! Is there a way I can search for it without using a hard-coded value like the contains(text) & store it in a variable? this is because the text values will change

Answer (score 0):

Xpath selector:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Acura West')]")
```

or css selector:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.ng-scope + span")
```

**EDIT:**

For more flexible selection use:

```
string name = "Acura West";
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{name}')]")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!! Is there a way I can search for it without using a hard-coded value like the contains(text) & store it in a variable? this is because the text values will change

Comment: You can do that. Use [string interpolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t want to search for a particular text, but rather for the element (as the text might change based on the listing/page), based on the HTML snippet you could use XPath such as:

```
# Matches elements with "item.name" in value of one of its attributes
//span[starts-with(@data-ng-bind, 'item.name')]
```

or

```
# Same as before, except it`s exact match of the particular attribute`s value
//span[contains(@data-ng-bind, 'item.name|wrapText')]
```